# Change height of column for animation

Tags: animation, qml, state

I have created a simple tree which I wish to animate by having branches height expand/collapse visually.  My code below works by switching only the visible attribute, so that if I click on the branch it can appear/disappear.

However I want to animate the height of the column from normal to 0 and back.    The problem is, the height of the column never changes when the state changes.  Why?

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Column {
    id: menuGroup
    property string path: "/"
    property bool _onCurrentPath: (treeMenu._currentPath.indexOf(path) === 0)

    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    spacing: 0
    // visible: _onCurrentPath  <-- this works

    states: [
        State {
            name: "HIDDEN"
            when: !_onCurrentPath
            PropertyChanges { target: menuGroup; height: 0}
        },
        State {
            name: "VISIBLE"
            when: _onCurrentPath
            PropertyChanges { target: menuGroup; height: 600 } //menuGroup.implicitHeight}
        }
    ]

    transitions: Transition {
        PropertyAnimation { property: "height"; duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }
    onStateChanged: {
        console.log("Group "+path+" state "+state)
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to force the height of a column?  (Do I have to wrap it in a Rectangle or some other solution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I noticed when running your code was that `onStateChanged` was not executing. It seems that your `when: _onCurrentPath` is not evaluating due to a scoping problem that does not trigger an error or warning. I changed this to `when: menuGroup._onCurrentPath` in both cases and I was able to start seeing the state changes.

Secondarily, I had to enable `clip: true` to make sure that the contents of the column were actually trimmed, otherwise it visually didn't make a difference that the column was collapsing, as the contents stayed visible.

Here is a full working example (modified your `_onCurrentPath` bool to simplify testing):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Column {
        id: menuGroup
        property string path: "/"
        property bool _onCurrentPath: button.checked

        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        spacing: 0
        clip: true // Must enable to actually clip contents of column when collapsing

        states: [
            State {
                name: "HIDDEN"
                when: !menuGroup._onCurrentPath // Must explicitly state menuGroup here
                PropertyChanges { target: menuGroup; height: 0}
            },
            State {
                name: "VISIBLE"
                when: menuGroup._onCurrentPath
                PropertyChanges { target: menuGroup; height: 600 } 
            }
        ]

        transitions: Transition {
            PropertyAnimation { property: "height"; duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
        }

        onStateChanged: {
            console.log("Group "+path+" state "+state)
        }

        Rectangle { // Some column content for demonstration
            color: "red"
            implicitHeight: 600
            implicitWidth: 200
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        checkable: true
        text: "Change States"
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you tell if state is changing?  (to debug)

Comment: Your onStateChanged console.log() line was sufficient. Prior to adding the menuGroup id, the log was not occurring, indicating state was not changing. After I added the menuGroup id, it occurred every time I change the state via my additional button.